# C++ comparing current day and time with current day and set time

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to compare two time values and display time that is left till upper limit, but I'm unable to do so with my knowledge.

Basic idea:

```
    if(now >= (today 8:15) and now <= (today 9:45) )
        ....display "first lecture ends in" (time left)
    .
    .
    else if 
    .
    .
    else 
        ....display "short break"
```

I just cant find any simple examples/solutions or it's my way of thinking that's wrong. I'm distinguishing days with

> tm_wday

and now I want to distinguish time intervals while comparing time values.

Comment: I dont know what I tried at this point, my code is a mess right now so I'm working on different part of that assigment, but I know I tried manually inserting dates and converting them to time, but thats not the result I want.

Comment: Get the current time with time() and then call localtime() to get a tm structure for the current time and then modify the hours minutes and seconds to be what you want and then call mktime() to get a specific time that you can compare with the original current time you made.

Comment: Use the [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library. Google for tutorials if you don't know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<chrono>` and `<ctime>` libraries to calculate the difference between two time points. For example:

```
std::tm t1;
t1.tm_year = 117;
t1.tm_mon = 10;
t1.tm_mday = 27;
t1.tm_hour = 8;
t1.tm_min = 15;
t1.tm_sec = 0;

std::tm t2;
t2.tm_year = 117;
t2.tm_mon = 10;
t2.tm_mday = 27;
t2.tm_hour = 10;
t2.tm_min = 15;
t2.tm_sec = 0;

std::time_t time_t1 = std::mktime(&t1);
std::time_t time_t2 = std::mktime(&t2);
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time_t1);
auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time_t2);

auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(end - start).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Howard Hinnant's free open-source timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), combined with `<chrono>` can do this with the following syntax.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now()).get_local_time();
    auto today = floor<days>(now);    
    if ((today + 8h + 15min) <= now and now <= (today + 9h + 45min))
        std::cout << format("first lecture ends in %H:%M\n",
                            today + 9h + 45min - now);
}
```

This just output for me:

```
first lecture ends in 00:59
```

The `make_zoned` line is how you get the current local time.  `now` is a type of `std::chrono::time_point` that is not based on any specific clock.

By using `floor<days>`, you can truncate that to a days-precision time_point that indicates the start of the day.

Using the C++14 chrono literals you can simply add the hours and minutes to `today` to get the lecture times.  In C++11, substitute `hours{8}` for `8h`.

### Update

[Howard Hinnant's free open-source timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) is now part of C++20 with just a few minor syntax changes.  The C++20 version of the above program looks like:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = zoned_time{current_zone(), system_clock::now()}.get_local_time();
    auto today = floor<days>(now);    
    if ((today + 8h + 15min) <= now and now <= (today + 9h + 45min))
        std::cout << std::format("first lecture ends in {:%H:%M}\n",
                            today + 9h + 45min - now);
}
```

Comment: This effectively implements the exact pseudo-code in the question, but subtracting out "today midnight" (the `today` variable) from all values would make it substantially simpler.  e.g. `time_now = now - today;  if (time_now >= 8h + 15min && time_now <= 9h + 45min)`